# Implementing a global dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In the application I'm currently working on, I have a requirement to show data filtered by a drop down list that should be available in every page.

For those familiar with the Amazon Web Services Management Console, the idea is pretty much the same as the Regions drop down list. So once you change the region, you see the resources (e.g. Instances, Volumes, Snapshots) available in that region. The selected region should be kept along all the subsequent requests until you select a different region.

Therefore I started by setting the drop down list in the master page and creating a global filter that sets all the possible values in the ViewBag.

I'd like to see the selected value in the query string, so I also put a form around the drop down list with the FormMethod set to use GET.

But that is all, I ran out of ideas on how to continue with this.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you link this question with an example of what you want to achieve? Seems like you can store the data in session variables and post the data on event change to store the state. If your target browsers are modern browsers you can also make use of localstorage in HTML5.

Comment: I cannot think of another example but the Amazon Web Services Console. Probably this is better: Imagine you have a drop down list with a list of available languages, and when you choose one, e.g. Spanish, you will see every page in spanish and the Urls will have a query string value like ?lang=sp in all subsequent requests. I don't want to use Session for this.

Comment: is in all the pages where dropdown exists r u binding any model or not?

Comment: Any specific reason for not wanting to use session? What about cookies?

Comment: @user1006544 as I explained, I created a global filter that puts in the ViewBag the data that should be bound to the drop down list on every request.

Comment: @Shouvik, I don't think I need session at all, I will be loading the list of possible values on every request and setting it in the ViewBag. The selected value in the drop down list will be inferred by the value of a Property in the current User.